# Merge two arrays of different lengths with key and 0 fill on empty

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge two arrays with keys in PHP. If no key defined for any array it should fill the value by zero. I wanted solution like

```
array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2)
```

But it does not produce the required output. I have coded following. It works but I want to know if there are any other good and efficient solution like `array_merge_recursive()`;

```
function array_combine_zero_fill($a1,$a2){
    $a3=array();
    foreach($a1 as $k=>$v){
        $a3[$k]['doc1']=$v;
        $a3[$k]['doc2']=array_key_exists($k, $a2) ? $a2[$k]:0;
    }
    foreach($a2 as $k=>$v){
        $a3[$k]['doc1']=array_key_exists($k, $a2) ? $a3[$k]['doc1']:0;
        $a3[$k]['doc2']=$v;
    }
    return $a3;
}
```

The array structure is like following

```
$a1 = array(
    "apple"=>4,
    "banana"=>2,
    "mango"=>10,
    "guava"=>1,
    "cherry"=>3,
    "grapes"=>7
    );
$a2 = array(
    "pista"=>77,
    "cashew"=>65,
    "almond"=>23,
    "guava"=>34,
    "cherry"=>54,
    "grapes"=>48
    );
```

The required result should look like this

```
a3 = Array(
    [apple] => Array([doc1] =>  4, [doc2] =>  0),    
    [banana] => Array([doc1] => 2, [doc2] =>  0),
    [mango] => Array([doc1] => 10, [doc2] =>  0),
    [guava] => Array([doc1] =>  1, [doc2] => 34),
    [cherry] => Array([doc1] => 3, [doc2] => 54),
    [grapes] => Array([doc1] => 7, [doc2] => 48),
    [pista] => Array([doc1] =>  0, [doc2] => 77),
    [cashew] => Array([doc1] => 0, [doc2] => 65),
    [almond] => Array([doc1] => 0, [doc2] => 23)
);
```

Comment: Post the array structure along with the expected output

Comment: I have updated the question with the array structure and output structure.

Comment: @Prabhu why are you even looping Array 1 if all you do is set any key that exists in both to 0 for Array 1. Take grapes for example, in the first loop you set the values to 7 and 48, but in loop two you overwrite them to 0 and 48... That's pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Find all unique keys
$keys = array_flip(array_merge(array_keys($a1), array_keys($a2)));

// create new array
foreach($keys as $k=>$v) {
  $result[$k]['doc1'] = isset($a1[$k]) ? $a1[$k] : 0;
  $result[$k]['doc2'] = isset($a2[$k]) ? $a2[$k] : 0;
  }

  var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't quite complete. Try this:

```
function array_combine_zero_fill($a1, $a2) {
    $a3=array();
    foreach($a1 as $k=>$v){
        $a3[$k]['doc1']=$v;
        $a3[$k]['doc2']=array_key_exists($k, $a2) ? $a2[$k]:0;
    }
    foreach($a2 as $k=>$v){
        // Only add to the array if it's not there, otherwise you just overwrite what was added in the first foreach above.
        if ( ! isset($a3[$k])) {
            $a3[$k]['doc1']=0;
            $a3[$k]['doc2']=$v;
        }
    }
    return $a3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( array_unique( array_keys( array_merge($a1,$a2) ) ) as $k )
{
    $output[$k]= array("doc1" => array_key_exists( $k, $a1 ) ? $a1[$k] : 0, "doc2" => array_key_exists( $k, $a2 ) ? $a2[$k] : 0 );
}

print_r($output);
```